# retrieving contents from liferay cms using java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, content-management-system, liferay

I have upload some files using Document and Media portlet in Liferay,Now want to download that particular contents from web service what should i do? I have no idea what would be the url hierarchy of retrieving that particular file? What api should i use? After Googling i found some libraries but that doesn't clear my concept.

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.html
http://liferaypower.blogspot.com/2013/04/getting-images-from-document-and-media.html

Comment: It might be best if you describe what you have tried and where it goes wrong. Currently your question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay exposes most of its functionality via WebServices. It supports both SOAP and REST+JSON style services. The choice is yours as to which way to go.

Here are links to Liferay documentation which should help you get started:

1. JSON: https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/JSON+Web+Services
2. SOAP: https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/soap-web-services

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had already made Webservice but i was using that service to retrieve data from alfresco repository my question is that how do i get contents from Liferay Repository usng same rest service.

Comment: What you're saying doesn't sound like you know what you're working on.